# Call MATLAB complex matrix function from C

Tags: c, matlab, mex, complex-numbers, matlab-compiler

I have created dll of matlab function makeSbus using matlab compiler sdk to use in C. The function takes 1 integer and 2 double matrix as input and give a complex double matrix as output. It creates sparse matrices during processing in MATLAB.
This is the MATLAB source code

```
function Sbus = makeSbus(baseMVA, bus, gen)

on = find(gen(:, 8) > 0); %% which generators are on?
gbus = gen(on, 1);               %% what buses are they at?
    


nb = size(bus, 1);
ngon = size(on, 1);
Cg = sparse(gbus, (1:ngon)', ones(ngon, 1), nb, ngon);  


%% connection matrix.element i, j is 1 if gen on(j) at bus i is ON
    Sbus =  ( Cg * (gen(on,2 ) + 1j * gen(on, 3))   - (bus(:, 3) + 
             1j * bus(:, 4)) ) / baseMVA;
```

The output ofsbus is a complex double matrix of 9*1 dimension.

Using data from Case 9 here, I get the following answer from MATLAB.

https://matpower.org/docs/ref/matpower5.0/case9.html

```
case1='case9.m';
A=loadcase(case1);
Sbus =makeSbus(A.baseMVA,A.bus, A.gen);
```

Sbus=
{0.7230 + 0.27030i,
1.63+ 0.0654i,
0.85 - 0.1095i,
0.0 + 0.0i,
-0.90- 0.30i,
0.0+ 0.0i,
-1.0 - 0.35i,
0.0 + 0.0i,
-1.25- 0.50i}

I wish to call this code from C. Used matlab compiler sdk to create the necessary library files. This is my code to call the function from C

```
mxArray* Bus, * Gen,*var;
mxArray* sbus = NULL;

Bus = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(9, 17, mxREAL);
Gen = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3, 25, mxREAL);
sbus = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(9, 1, mxCOMPLEX);
var = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
int data1[]={100};
double B[9][13], G[3][21];
// reads B and G matrix from a csv file


memcpy(mxGetPr(Bus), B, 9 * 13 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(mxGetPr(Gen), G, 3 * 21 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(mxGetPr(var), data1, sizeof(int));
    

if (!makeSbusInitialize()) 
   {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize the library.\n");
        return -2;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Call the library function */

        mlfMakeSbus(1, &sbus, var, Bus, Gen);
      size_t i = 0, j = 0; /* loop index variables */
      size_t r = 0, c = 0; /* variables to store the row and column 
      length of the matrix */
      double* data; /* variable to point to the double data stored 
      within the mxArray */

      /* Get the size of the matrix */
      r = mxGetM(sbus);
      c = mxGetN(sbus);
      /* Get a pointer to the double data in mxArray */
      data = mxGetPr(sbus);
       for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
       {
          for (j = 0; j < r; j++)
          {
            printf("%4.2f\t", data[j * c + i]);
          }
          printf("\n");
       }
      printf("\n");

      makeSbusTerminate();
   }
```

when I compile it, it shows "Error using sparse
Index into matrix must be positive" .The error is when it is trying to create Cg sparse matrix inside makesbus function.

Any idea how to debug it? Also, if I get a complex matrix as my output from matlab function, how to read it from C? Is the approach I'm taking here right? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. I assume this code resides inside a mex, and the entry point is `mexFunction`, so we need to see it all, together with a usage example from the matlab side. Also please post a well-indented code. Lack of proper indentation makes it hard to read.

Comment: C has no concept of matrix, for C a bidimensional array is just that, so I suppose the problem comes frrom the matlab function. In matlab, index start at 1 while in C they usually start at 0. So pls check if you are addressing matlab function with a index = 0.

Comment: @wohlstad I have updated the question and included an example. Please have a look and let me know if you know the wway around the issue mentioned here.

Comment: @LexFerrinson not sure how to change the index here. Like I mentioned, I read the input matrices from a csv file in C and copied them to mxarrays to be used in matlab. As far as I know, the index starts from 1 in MATLAB by default for all its array/matrices.

Comment: `mxGetPr(var)`, but you never create this matrix. `var` is not assigned anything prior to this. You could use `var = mxCreateDoubleScalar(100)`.

Comment: @LexFerrinson This is the sparse command that's creating the issue inside makeSbus. 
Cg = sparse(gbus, (1:ngon)', ones(ngon, 1), nb, ngon);
I tried adding 1 with the row and column index of sparse.
nb is #of rows in the input matrix bus.
Cg = sparse(gbus, (1:ngon)', ones(ngon, 1), nb+1, ngon+1);
However, it still shows the same error.

Comment: It is unclear to me which variable is sparse. Is it the "in" variable? If so, you cannot index into the data area with two nested for-loops like you have shown ... that method only works for full matrices. Also, your B and G variables are ordered in memory in row-major order, whereas your Bus and Gen mxArray variables are ordered in memory in column-major order. So it looks like you have a mismatch in memory order for the data. The dimensions of what you are copying also don't match, but maybe that is intentional to copy only part of the data? Can you clarify all this?

Comment: @JamesTursa I have edited the question and included the source code of the matlab function I'm trying to call from C. The sparse matrix call is insidee the function. The final output is a complex double matrix sbus.  I've noticed the mismatch in the memory order.  Do you think the error is because of that?
"The dimensions of what you are copying also don't match, but maybe that is intentional to copy only part of the data? Can you clarify all this? "- not sure which part you are talking about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the problems I see with your latest edits:

Incorrect access of sparse data (assuming sbus is sparse):
Sparse matrices only physically store the non-zero elements. E.g., if the matrix size is 10x10 but only 7 elements are non-zero, then there are only 7 elements physically stored in memory, not 100 elements. If you try to access these elements with two nested for-loops like you are doing via the code data[j * c + i] where i and j ranges are based on matrix size, you will access invalid memory and crash MATLAB. You have to have special code to access the elements of a sparse matrix that takes into account the indexes of the non-zero elements that are stored in the variable. See the mxGetIr and mxGetJc functions to get access to these indexes. E.g., this code snippet would simply print the data using 1-based indexing for output:

```
mwIndex *Ir, *Jc, nrow, k=0; /* k will count how far we are into the sparse data */
Ir = mxGetIr(sbus); /* pointer to row indexes */
Jc = mxGetJc(sbus); /* pointer to cumulative number of elements up to this column */
for( j=0; j<n; j++ ) { /* for each column */
    nrow = Jc[j+1] - Jc[j];  /* number of non-zero row elements stored for this column */
    while(nrow--) { /* for each stored element in this column */
        printf("sbus(%d,%d) = %4.2f\n", Ir[k]+1,j+1,data[k]); /* 1-based index output */
        k++; /* increment counter */
    }
}
```

In the above, note that sparse index data is stored as 0-based values, even though when you print it out at the MATLAB level the indexing displayed is 1-based. The above code prints out the elements in the 1st column, then the 2nd column, etc. I.e., the elements are stored in memory in column order, so as we march through the data in memory order it gets printed out naturally in column order.

CAVEAT: The above code assumes the sparse matrix is real. If the sparse matrix is complex, then there is the imaginary data to consider. Methods to access the real & imaginary data vary depending on whether you are using R2018a+ interleaved complex memory model or R2017b- separate complex memory model. Which version of MATLAB are you using and which memory model are you compiling with? This will affect how to write the code for element access. For the R2018a+ memory model, it is simply two elements per spot instead of one. E.g., something like this:

```
    printf("sbus(%d,%d) = %4.2f + %4.2f i\n", Ir[k]+1,j+1,data[2*k],data[2*k+1]); /* 1-based index output */
```

Mismatch of matrix sizes:
The mxArrays Bus and Gen are created as 9x17 and 3x25, but your C variables B and G are declared as [9][13] and [3][21]. They don't match. So during your data copying there are elements that don't get set.

Mismatch of element order in memory:
mxArray matrix elements are ordered in memory column-wise, whereas native C matrix elements are ordered in memory row-wise. In essence, they are transposes of each other in memory. You can't just memcpy the elements because the ordering is different. You would need to read the data in differently, or transpose the matrix when you do the data copy.

Incorrect copy of int to double:
data1 is type int, but the mxArray var is type double. You can't copy an int bit pattern (data1) into a double (data area of mxArray var) via memcpy ... results will be garbage. Use an assignment instead. E.g., something like this would work:

```
*mxGetPr(var) = data1[0];
```

Or you could create var directly from data1[0] like this:

```
var = mxCreateDoubleScalar(data1[0]);
```